# C programming Fahrenheit to celsius error conversion using a function with static

Tags: c, function, for-loop, static, int

So I'm writing a fun program that converts celsius to Fahrenheit and I'm using a function with static. My current code looks like this and I basically want to know the error here because beside the first column of numbers all the numbers appear to be `2686824.`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int table(int fahr, int celsius) {
    static int total = 0;
    total += fahr;
    total += celsius;
    return total;
}

int main () {

   int i;
   int n = 20;
   int conversion = (n-32) * (5/9);
   printf("Temperature conversion program\n");

   for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      printf("%d %6d\n", table(n, conversion));
   }
}
```

Comment: printf("%d %6d\n", table(n, conversion)); you are passing only one parameter

Comment: This is for fun (and not, e.g. a homework; I mention this because the Fahrenheit-Celsius is so very typical as a homework assignment). Your fun code however is so far from your stated goal, that I humbly suggest to choose your next fun project with an eye to this veryhelpful article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ Or maybe go all the way to a HelloWorld and then start extending your knowledge with the help of some basic tutorials. For the purpose of fun, this is a much more success-promising path. And experiencing success is so important for having fun.

Answer (score 0):

your program does not convert anything. It just adds the both values.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double toCelc(double fahr)
{
    return (fahr - 32.0) * (5.0/9.0); 
}

double toFahr(double celc)
{
    return celc * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0;
}


int main()
{
    for(int c = -30; c < 40; c++)
    {
        printf("F: %.2f\t\tC:%.2f\n", toFahr(c), (double)c);
    }

    for(int f = -30; f < 100; f++)
    {
        printf("F: %.2f\t\tC:%.2f\n", (double)f, toCelc(f));
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You calculate only one time

```
int conversion = (n-32) * (5/9);
```

and n is always 20

```
table(n, conversion)
```

So its always the same parameter